# Java Pack No Resize

Tags: java, swing, resize

i am learning Java at the moment and have the following question:

i am adding my controls to JFrame and then pack() before displaying.

this runs the application and all is very nice.

i was wondering is there a way to stop the user from resizing the application window?

also is there a way to for the image in JLabel to expand as the user changes the application window?

at the moment i have it as:

```
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
```

and it only centers the image, i would like to be able to expand/shrink the image.

thanks.

Comment: I don't need to set my frames unresizable. I always use Matisse in NetBeans IDE. It is the best and free GUI editor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i was wondering is there a way to stop
>   the user from resizing the application
>   window?

If you don't want to allow users to resize your window at all then you can do

```
frame.setResizable (false);
```

---

I'm not sure that this technique can be successfully used at the same time with `pack()`. You should certainly try, but I remember there was an issue that if you do:

```
frame.setResizable (false);
pack();
```

then `pack()` simply doesn't do what it should and if you do:

```
pack();
frame.setResizable(false);
```

then you window becomes a little more narrow then after only `pack()`. Of course, some workaround can be found (or maybe even it's just my bad experience).

Comment: this.setResizable(false); pack(); this worked. the other way it produced a different result by introducing some padding around the controls.

Comment: @ikurtz: that's nice! I tried it with java 1.4, maybe something changed since then.

Comment: thanks for the help. im using Java 1.6.0_17 and NetBeans 6.8. glad it is working!

Answer (score 2):

for the first question, you can stop the user from resizing your window using the method [`setResizable(boolean)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setResizable(boolean)):

```
frame.setResizable(false);
```

I don't use `GridBagLayout`, so I can't help you with the second question.

Comment: The second question is not related to the use of GridBagLayout, but how to scale the image in a JLabel.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent resizing the window, you can simply call `setResizable(false)` on your Window or (J)Frame.

As to the JLabel and image, there is no easy way to make it scale the image according to it's actual size. If you use the label just for the image (no text), it's probably easier for you to implement your own component, in which you paint the image yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
also is there a way to for the image in JLabel to expand as the user changes the application window?
```

Yes you need to create your own `LabelUI` class and set it to your label via `setUI()`.
In your custom LabelUI class, you will have to override `getPreferredSize` and paint the imageIcon as you wish.

It is slightly programmatic, you may want to look at source of `BasicLabelUI` to understand how things are done.( http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Apache-Harmony-Java-SE/javax-package/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicLabelUI.java.htm )

or

you could over-ride `paintComponent()` API of JLabel by creating your own extended JLabel class.