# Not displaying strings

Tags: java, string, swing, graphics

So I have made a program that is supposed to display a series of strings, 14 X 14 long, to the screen. It used to work when you changed the size but I made setResizable false, so now I can
't see anything. I appreciate all of your help. Here is the code:

```
private Color textColor = Color.BLACK;
private Random random = new Random();
String[][] letters = new String[14][14];

float fontsize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 50;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(textColor);
    setFont(getFont().deriveFont(fontsize));

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {  
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            if ((int) (Math.random() * 100) > 97) {
                letters[i][j] = "w";
                textColor = Color.BLUE;
                System.out.println("asd");
            } else {
                letters[i][j] = "l";
                textColor = new Color(0, 100, 0);
            }

            g.drawString(letters[i][j], i * 34, j * 34);

            if (i >= 99)
                System.out.println("asdasdasd");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // repaint();
}

public mainClass() {
    setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 3, 
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width / 3 + 80);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Timer timer = new Timer(500, this);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.start();

    setResizable(false);        
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mainClass myWindow = new mainClass();
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? This isn't a debugging service.

Comment: Don't override paint(). Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do custom painting. If you still need more help then post a `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'm confused. How the following should be understood:  "*It used to work when you changed the size **but I made setResizable false**, so now I can 't see anything. I appreciate all of your help.*"

Comment: I'm sorry I would explain but I am a very novice programmer and I honestly have no idea what is going on.

EDIT: @PM 77-1 I'm trying to make a game and I don't want the window to be resizable. Before, if you dragged at the side of the window to change it's size or maximized it, the Strings would appear, but now that I changed it to setResizable(false) it obviously doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with then?

Comment: `I would explain but I am a very novice programmer` - so where is your SSCCE. Words don't help us!

Comment: See the answers [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639343/java-pack-no-resize) for any helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with your `JFrame` being re-sized by the program (not by users), you can try `pack()` that is supposed to work even with `setResizable` set as `false`.

If however you don't want to allow any type of re-sizing, then you need to explain your question further.